# How to decode registry value using winreg

Tags: python, registry, decode, winreg

I have this code

```
from winreg import *
aReg=ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
aKey=OpenKey(aReg, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent')
aKey=EnumValue(aKey, 0)
print(aKey[1])
```

And when I run it, it returns this `b'\xb3\xec\xff\x00\x80\xe0\xff\x00Y\xd6\xff\x00)\xa4\xcc\x00\x00s\x99\x00\x00Ws\x00\x00:M\x00\x88\x17\x98\x00'`

but in registry editor, it looks like this:

[image]

I want to ask, how to decode the first to second.
Thanks for any reply. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this, works :)

```
from winreg import *

def getAccentColor():  
    """
    Return the Windows 10 accent color used by the user in a HEX format
    """
    registry = ConnectRegistry(None,HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
    key = OpenKey(registry, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent')
    key_value = QueryValueEx(key,'AccentColorMenu')
    accent_int = key_value[0]
    accent = accent_int-4278190080
    accent = str(hex(accent)).split('x')[1]
    accent = accent[4:6]+accent[2:4]+accent[0:2]
    return '#'+accent
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a particular value (rather than enumerating each value one at a time), you can use the `QueryValueEx()` function as follows:

```
from winreg import *

hreg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
hkey = OpenKey(hreg, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent')
accent_color_menu = QueryValueEx(hkey, 'AccentColorMenu')[0]
CloseKey(hkey)

print(accent_color_menu)
```

This would give you something like:

```
4292311040
```

Comment: How I can convert it to hex?

Comment: You mean as a string? `print(hex(accent_color_menu))` would do it.

Comment: The value is probably not a simple RGB setting, it might be HSL format or possibly it points to a theme elsewhere in the registry.

Comment: And can I somehow find that theme. I need color code for that color, which is used on live tiles, taskbar, start, action center.

Comment: Try using the Windows "Choose your accent colour" dialog to select different colours and see how the value changes in the registry depending on the colour selected. Also do some internet searches for `AccentColorMenu`.